# How do I convert all nonumeric values to NAs in R in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called returns. How do I make the code below more concise? I tried using apply, lappply and sapply, but they seem to change the structure of the dataframe such that I cannot produce a correlation matrix. To clarify: the code below works, but I would like to make it more concise. Thanks!

```
returns$VIT <- as.numeric(as.character(returns$VIT))
returns$EFA <- as.numeric(as.character(returns$EFA))
returns$VWO <- as.numeric(as.character(returns$VWO))
returns$VIG <- as.numeric(as.character(returns$VIG))
returns$VNQ <- as.numeric(as.character(returns$VNQ))
returns$iPath.DJP <- as.numeric(as.character(returns$iPath.DJP))
returns$iShares.MUB <- as.numeric(as.character(returns$iShares.MUB))

cor(returns, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

EDIT: The following test code does NOT work, I am trying to figure out how to make it work.

```
test <- data.frame(c(.04,.2,"blah"),c(.01,.24,"blah"))
colnames(test) <- c("VIT", "EFA")

new <- apply(test, 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
cor(test, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

Comment: Try `apply(returns, 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))`.  Welcome to SO.  It's the general practice that when you can, you include a small reproducible example so we can run your code.

Comment: Doing new <- apply(returns, 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))) creates rows [1,] [2,] instead of 1,2. And I cannot run cor(returns, use="pairwise.complete.obs")

Comment: Be specific.  What doesn't work.  What's the error? Plus you're running `cor` on test not new.

Answer (score 0):

```
test <- data.frame(a = rep("bob", 12), b = rep(c(1,23,4), times = 4))
Filter(is.numeric, test)
```

Returns only the numeric columns in `test`. You can use `lapply(test, is.numeric)` to get the true/false results yourself and do something with that.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I'm not trying to remove the columns with any nonumeric values. Rather, some columns have entries that are nonnumeric and I want to mark those as NA so that I can get a correlation matrix

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
numeric.columns <- c('VIT','EFA','VWO','VIG','VNQ','iPath.DJP','iPath.DJP','iShares.MUB')
returns[,numeric.columns] <- lapply(returns[,numeric.columns], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
cor(returns, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

Comment: returns[,numeric.columns] <- lapply(returns[,numeric.columns], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))) does not successfully coerce the nonnumeric values into NAs

Comment: That's surprising. It does for me (and throw a warning to that effect). Can you post a minimal data set on which we might be able to reproduce this?

Comment: I also get the warning, but there aren't any NAs afterwards. Strangely, your code DOES work with the test code that I provided in the original post, but not with the real data. Here is a sample row of returns after running your suggested code: 2167  0.016311  0.015539         #N/A         #N/A      #DIV/0!         #N/A         #N/A  0.005235602

Comment: And what's that line _before_ the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `plyr`'s `colwise`.

```
returns = colwise(function(x) as.numeric(ifelse(is.numeric(x),x,NA)))(returns)
```

It takes a function and applies it to all columns.  The final result should be numeric.  Note that this treats values such as `'1'` as NA.